# Stop Thread in background

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Can any body please help me out?
My problem is I have a thread(TCP socket) class in android which starts when android app login but I want to stop thread when application is in background, please let me know how can I do it? because it is consuming huge cpu performance and ram also hanging my device.

Comment: You can use lifecycle methods like onPause() or onStop()

Comment: 'because it is consuming huge cpu performance and ram also hanging my device' well, you could always fix your design so that does not happen...

Comment: fix the design means?

Answer (score 0):

Base on my experience, you can set the timeout to a very short number, and close the Socket if your app goes to background.

Let me explain more...

1. register a permission to receive the event of app-goes-to-background
2. start a new Socket with very short timeout setting.
3. when you received the event of app-goes-to-background, mark a global flag
4. while waiting for new message from remote server that connected by the Socket, a exception will be trigger when timed-out. During this situation, check the abovementioned global flag. If the flag shows your are in app-goes-to-background status, close the socket (and maybe trigger another thread to check the status of the global flag, so that you can start a new Socket). If the flag shows you are NOT in the background, just keep receiving new message from remote server (and wait for next timeout).